# How to categorize positive and negative features from top features

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have trained user reviews thru average tfidf wor2vec model and got top features. Would like to tag top features as positive & negative.

Could you please suggest.

```
def top_tfidf_feats(row, features, top_n=1):
    ''' Get top n tfidf values in row and return them with their corresponding feature names.'''
    topn_ids = np.argsort(row)[::-1][:top_n]
    top_feats = [(features[i], row[i]) for i in topn_ids]
    df = pd.DataFrame(top_feats)
    df.columns = ['feature', 'tfidf']
    return df

top_tfidf = top_tfidf_feats(final_tf_idf[1,:].toarray()[0],tfidf_feat,10)
```

```
Top 10 features...
feature     tfidf
-------     ------
0   urgent  0.513783
1   tells   0.501945
2   says    0.490708
3   clear   0.424756
4   care    0.206723
5   not 0.141886
6   flanum  0.000000
7   flap    0.000000
8   flare   0.000000
9   flared  0.000000
10  flares  0.000000
```

Comment: How did you select top features from your tfidf transformation?

Comment: Reviews were passed to text vectorizer, got feature names and corresponding tfidf values and printed them in descending order.